# Can we use "has_object_permission" in ViewSet patch methods

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, permissions

I'm trying to check is model instance writable before updating but my `has_object_permission` is not called in my custom permission class:

```
class IsOrderInstanceWritable(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.state != obj.States.REVIEWED
```

My Viewset:

```
class ResultUtilViewSet(ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOrderInstanceWritable]

    @action(methods=["patch"], detail=False)
    def patch_result(self, request):
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
            result = Results.objects.filter(
                order=data["order"], analysis__short_name=data["analysis"]
            )
            result.update(
                value=data["value"],
            )
            update_order_state(data["order"])
        except Exception as err:
            logger.error(f"could not update results: {repr(err)}")
            return Response(repr(err), status=500)
        return Response()
```

Am I misusing permission classes? Any pointers on this would be appreciated. Thanks.